# Polynomial curve fitting and support vector machines

Tags: regression, svm, polynomial

I applied regression using support vector machines and then I approximate the results using polynomial regression and obtain an equation for the results. I applied support vector machines and then polynomial regression because I didn't know how to obtain equation directly from applying support vector machines.

My questions are:

- Is it correct to apply support vector machine and then polynomial regression?
- Is it possible to get regression equation from applying only support vector machine?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: guys I really need an answer. I hope the question was clear.

Comment: You must have patience to get an answer here...

Comment: Your question is not clear. To _what_ did you apply polynomial regression (what was your independent/dependent variables)? In order to get a better/quicker answer, it is also highly recommended for you to post a reproducible code example.

Comment: I first did regression using support vector machine approach, my dependent vairable is the cost and my independent variable was the change in network condition. Then I applied polynomial regression to the results that I obtained from the support vector machine regression model to get approximate mathematical equation of the relation between the dependent and the independent variables obtained from support vector machine regression I hope this was clear